# Inserting Object in YAML in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, npm, yaml

I am using https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml to process YAML files.

How can I insert an object in midst of YAML file without converting to JSON and dumping back to YAML? (Converting and dumping back removes some of custom attributes and comments)

Comment: round-tripping YAML parsers are rare and js-yaml is not one of them. Even those which advertise it do not completely round-trip. It is unlikely that you can achieve what you want with js-yaml.

Comment: yes, found similar result after a week of research, viva RegEx :)